# Finally block is running before Promise.all() finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-postgres

I'm working on a script to seed my database but am having issues with my node-pg connection being terminated before my rebuild function is finished.

```
const rebuildDB = async () => {
  try {
    client.connect();
    await dropTables();
    await createTables();
    await Promise.all(employees.map(createEmployee), customers.map(createCustomer));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } finally {
    client.end();
  }
};

rebuildDB();
```

When I remove the finally block everything runs correctly. If i leave it, the createEmployee function will execute but the connection will be terminated before createCustomer() is able to execute.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `await Promise.all(employees.map(createEmployee), customers.map(createCustomer));` is incorrect, it'll handle the promises from `employees.map(createEmployee)` but not from `customers.map(createCustomer)`; `Promise.all` completely ignores all but its first argument. You wanted `await Promise.all([...employees.map(createEmployee), ...customers.map(createCustomer)]);` or `await Promise.all([Promise.all(employees.map(createEmployee)), Promise.all(customers.map(createCustomer))]);`

Comment: `Promise.all` only takes one argument doesn't it? You've passed it two arrays, I bet the `createCustomer` calls aren't being awaited since that parameter is unused. Maybe try spreading both of those arrays into one?

Comment: `await Promise.all([...employees.map(createEmployee), ...customers.map(createCustomer)]);` gives you a single array result with all of the promise results. `await Promise.all([Promise.all(employees.map(createEmployee)), Promise.all(customers.map(createCustomer))]);` gives you an array with two elements, the first being the array from `employees` and the second from `customers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Reposting [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75951741/finally-block-is-running-before-promise-all-finished#comment133962291_75951741) as a proper answer (and adding to it):*

There are two issues. The main one, which you asked about, is that you're calling [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) incorrectly. It accepts only a **single** argument, not multiple arguments, so it's ignoring the promises from the second argument entirely. You want to pass in a *single* iterable (probably an array in this case).

The other problem is that you don't want `client.connect()` inside the `try`, since you don't want to call `client.end()` if `client.connect()` throws.

So:

```
const rebuildDB = async () => {
    // This shouldn't be *inside* the `try`, since you don't want to call
    // `client.end()` if this fails
    client.connect();  // <=== Does this need an await? It doesn't have one in your question...
    try {
        await dropTables();
        await createTables();
        // Pass a single array to `Promise.all`
        await Promise.all([...employees.map(createEmployee), ...customers.map(createCustomer)]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        client.end();
    }
};

rebuildDB();
```

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if `client.connect()` and `client.end()` need an `await`. I have not had issues leaving it out. The node-postgres docs don't really specify. They seem to use `await` in one example but all the others do not use it. I will move it out of the `try` block though

Comment: @JamesKehs - [Looks like](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/packages/pg/lib/client.js#L160) they both return promises (when you don't provide a callback), so yes, you should be using `await`.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat your two promises arrays in order to have the one expected iterable argument

```js
await Promise.all(
  employees.map(createEmployee)
    .concat(
      customers.map(createCustomer)
    )
);
```

This is equivalent in terms of result with the spread operator given in other answers. However if your arrays are very large (and I assume they could be if they are all the entries from a db) the spread operator could throw a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. Concat is more efficient on large arrays, especially if you only have two arrays to merge.

Read more about this on https://www.educative.io/answers/spread-operator-vs-arrayprototypeconcat-in-javascript